# How to handle JSON array empty using Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, retrofit, gson

I am using Retrofit lib for API call in my Android application. My JSON is like this.

```
 {"options": [
    {         
      "type": "item",
      "type_id": "19E9E453-64C6-41C9-BFB7-D6EFB8AF68B8",
      "key": "ageRange",
      "value": "Early 30s"         
    },
    {
      "type": "item",
      "type_id": "19E9E453-64C6-41C9-BFB7-D6EFB8AF68B8",
      "key": "colors",
      "value": "Black, Red"

    }
]}
```

Or

```
 {"options": []}
```

My model code is:

```java
@SerializedName("options")
@Expose
private ArrayList<OptionsDataModel> options;
```

So if `options` is not empty the code working fine but if `options` is empty I am getting error invalid item. So can any one help to solve this problem.

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1554 hope this might help you

Comment: It should work fine. What is the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score -1):

You can add a check in your response method for `result.body != null` before parsing your response to your object

Comment: always result.body != null is true

Comment: So if one of your item in the response is empty, the code is not working? Or do you mean the whole response is empty?